# How to make libusb library visible to another program?

Tags: linux, gcc, compilation

I am trying to compile [hidapi](http://code.google.com/p/open-zwave/source/browse/#svn/trunk/cpp/hidapi/linux) library. In order to compile that, I need [libusb-1.0](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/libusb/libusb-1.0/libusb-1.0.8/libusb-1.0.8.tar.bz2). I've downloaded that, configured, made and installed to `/usr/local/lib`. But when I try to compile `hidapi`, it doesn't see `libusb-1.0`:

> cc -Wall -g -c -I../hidapi `pkg-config libusb-1.0 --cflags`
>   hid-libusb.c -o hid-libusb.o -L/usr/local/lib Package libusb-1.0 was
>   not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the
>   directory containing `libusb-1.0.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH
>   environment variable No package 'libusb-1.0' found /bin/sh: cc: not
>   found make: *** [hid-libusb.o] Error 127

How can I fix that?

(compilation happens on Synology NAS)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you installed to `/usr/local/lib`, `pkg-config` will not find your installation unless you set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` appropriately

Try running:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig"
```

in your shell and then re-attempting to build your code