# Package libusb was not found in the pkg-config search path

Tags: pkg-config, libusb-1.0

I have installed pkg-config and libusb through brew

Now if I do

> pkg-config --cflags --libs libusb

I get below message

> Package libusb was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps
>   you should add the directory containing `libusb.pc' to the
>   PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable No package 'libusb' found

So I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157898/how-to-make-libusb-library-visible-to-another-program) post and did

> export
>   PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/libusb/1.0.20/lib/pkgconfig"

But I still have the problem. What am I missing?

I am using MAC OSX El Capitan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just run:

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs /usr/local/Cellar/libusb/1.0.20/lib/pkgconfig/libusb-1.0.pc
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem appears to be that homebrew installs libusb with the -1.0 appended to the package and file names. So:

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs libusb-1.0
```

will find it, while:

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs libusb
```

won't. Since many ./configure and other scripts are looking for it without the -1.0 appended, they fail. To me, this looks like a bug in the homebrew package. Manually creating a non-1.0 named version worked for me, but it's not a very elegant solution.

**Edit**

Based on the comment from @silverdr, try running

```
brew install libusb-compat
```

and see if that works for older packages that demand the non-1.0 package. And/or update what you're trying to compile to add the -1.0 and run it through the tests/validation to ensure it works with the newer version.

Comment: AFAIK the "non-1.0 named" is still reserved for `libusb-compat` / `libusb-legacy`. IOW - if you have `libusb-compat` installed you'll get the "non-1.0 named" one too.

Answer (score 0):

I have the the same problem. This work for me (Ubuntu):

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
```

Comment: An answer specific to Ubuntu's (Debian's) package manager is not applicable to macOS, though...